# Find all the function following the "factorial law"

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, reference-request, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Well playing with integral and WA I have found something (maybe?) solid .

We begin with two examples and no proof is mentioned here and because I strongly believe it's not new I add the tag "reference-request".

### First example :

Well we work with integral :

> > Let $n\geq 1$ a natural number then define :
> > $$\int_{}^{}x^n\ln(e^x-1)dx$$

Put $n=5$ we get :

$$\int_{}^{}z^5\ln(e^z-1)dz= -x^5 \operatorname{Li_2}(e^x) + 5 x^4 \operatorname{Li_3}(e^x) - 20 x^3 \operatorname{Li_4}(e^x) + 60 x^2 \operatorname{Li_5}(e^x) - 120 x \operatorname{Li_6}(e^x) + 120 \operatorname{Li_7}(e^x) - \frac{1}{6} x^6 \log(1 - e^x) + \frac{1}{6} x^6 \log(e^x - 1) + \operatorname{constant}
$$

In this example we see that if we multiply a coefficient by the exponent we get the next coefficient .Call this the "factorial law"

### Second example :

> > Let $n\geq 1$ a natural number then define :
> > $$\int_{}^{} y^n \operatorname{W(y)}dy $$

$$\int_{}^{} y^5 \operatorname{W(y)} dy = \frac{(x^6 (1944 \operatorname{W(x)}^7 - 324 \operatorname{W(x)}^6 + 324 \operatorname{W(x)}^5 - 270 \operatorname{W(x)}^4 + 180 \operatorname{W(x)}^3 - 90 \operatorname{W(x)}^2 + 30 \operatorname{W(x)} - 5))}{(11664 \operatorname{W(x)}^6)} + \operatorname{constant}$$

Here we have $x^6$ to find the "law" multiply the first coefficient (here $-5$) by $6$ and divide by the exponent of Lambert's function to get the next coefficient .

Well now my question :

As in my first example can we find all the function $f(x)$ continuous and integrable such that it follows the "factorial law" describe above ?

Be gentle because I think it's really hard .

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: In both examples, you've written definite integrals, but the answers you've produced involve the variable of integration, $x$. You might want to fix this, and to look carefully at the rest of what you've written to make sure you're not wasting the time of people who might choose to look at this question. (I, for instance, won't be looking at it any more because sloppily-formed questions often prove to be a waste of time for me; others may find some satisfaction in answering them, however.)

Comment: The best thing that I can think of is integration by part, $\int f(x)x^n dx =F(x)x^n- n\int f(x)x^{n-1} dx +C $ , this then can be used to integrate by table

Comment: This is as difficult as asking for laws to evaluate $\int f\,dx$. The only special case is when $a=0$ and $b=+\infty$ as that is the definition of a Mellin transform.

Comment: See my edits ! Thanks you !